# Subquery data in AngularFirestoreCollection snapshotChanges result

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying  to query a collection and change the data result based on another query return.

My chat structure is like this:

```
let chat = {
  id: "userId1" + "userId2",
  lastMessage: "",
  timestamp: "",
  title: ""
}
```

I need to split the chat id, query oneof the users and set the username as the chat title.

I tried to do this but is not working and doesn't showing result on template.

```
listChats(userId: string): Observable<any[]> {
return <Observable<any[]>>this.afs.collection(this.CHATS_COLLECTION)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .map((c) => {
    return c
      .filter((chat) => chat.payload.doc.id.startsWith(userId) || chat.payload.doc.id.endsWith(userId))
      .map(c => {
        const chatData = c.payload.doc.data() as Chat;
        const chatId = c.payload.doc.id;

        //the id here comes like "id1 + id2"
        let ids: string[] = c.payload.doc.id.split(this.SEPARADOR);

        //get the id 
        let id =  ids[0];

        //check in firebase the user row
        return this.afs.doc("users/" + id)
            .snapshotChanges()
            .map((c) =>{
                const data = c.payload.data() as User;
                let name = data.name;

                //Here I need to get the user name and set on the chat data
                chatData.title = name;

                return { chatId, ...chatData };

            });

      });

  });}
```

The ChatPage.ts:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.chats = this.chatService.listChats(userId);

  }
```

To diplay the chats on template:

```
<ion-list no-line>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let chat of chats | async" (click)="onOpenChat(chat)">
      <h2>{{chat.title}}</h2>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: are you getting correct `name` here `chatData.title = name;` as expected?

Comment: @Hareesh yes. take a look at the `let name = data.name;`

Comment: check `userId` is not `null` while `ionViewDidLoad()`

Comment: checking this question i tried to show another fields from Chat model on template and for my surprise just the `chatData.title` changed before is not appearing. Putting a breakpoint on this line `return { chatId, ...chatData };` the code never stops.

Answer (score 1):

use `.valueChanges()` to subscribe to the observable.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.chats = this.chatService.listChats(userId).valueChanges();

}
```

Try these changes

```
listChats(userId: string): Observable<any> {
return this.afs.collection(this.CHATS_COLLECTION)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .map((c) => {
    return c
      .filter((chat) => chat.payload.doc.id.startsWith(userId) || chat.payload.doc.id.endsWith(userId))
      .map(c => {
        const chatData = c.payload.doc.data() as Chat;
        const chatId = c.payload.doc.id;

        //the id here comes like "id1 + id2"
        let ids: string[] = c.payload.doc.id.split(this.SEPARADOR);

        //get the id 
        let id =  ids[0];

        //check in firebase the user row
        return this.afs.doc("users/" + id)
            .snapshotChanges()
            .map((c) =>{
                const data = c.payload.data() as User;
                let name = data.name;

                //Here I need to get the user name and set on the chat data
                chatData.title = name;

                return { chatId, ...chatData };

            });

      });

});}
```

Comment: Yes this piece of code works for me too. But my problem is that I'm trying to get the method return with a Chat array manipulated.

Comment: In fact I need an Observable<any[]> as return to use in a async component

Comment: In fact I need an Observable<any[]> as return to use in a async component

Comment: ok i think i misunderstand your question. so your `listChats()` returns nothing right.

Comment: Yes! That's my problem

Comment: how you displaying it in html?

Comment: i just updated the question to show the page and template code.